# preg_replace - leaving in unwanted characters

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've got a string:

```
$string = "Hello World!";
```

I want to turn it into a URL friendly tag, and I've developed a function to do it:

```
function stripJunk($string){
    $string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]\s/", "", $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);
    return $string;
}
```

However, when I run my `$string` through it above, I get the following:

```
$string = "hello-world!";
```

It seems that there are characters slipping through my preg_replace, even though from what I understand, they shouldn't be.

It should read like this:

```
$string = "hello-world";
```

What's going on here? (This should be easy peasy lemon squeasy!)

**Edit 1**: I wasn't aware that regular expressions were beginners stuff, but whatever. Additionally, removing the \s in my string does not produce the desired result.

The desired result is:

1. All spaces are converted to dashes.
2. All remaining characters that are not A-Z or 0-9 are removed.
3. The string is then converted to lower case.

**Edit 2+**: Cleaned up my code just a little.

Comment: in your present form you code makes little sense. All spaces are replaced in the first step, therefore `str_replace` does nothing.

Comment: I think it's harsh editing the question so that the original problem is removed. it makes previously useful answers look stupid

Comment: The problem I was having with preg_replace. I did not change the mathcing statement I used. Look through the revision history - the matching statement I have used since the beginning has remained unchanged. I changed the code for several reasons: 1) I wanted to focus on the problem I was having, and 2) not to focus on the fact that I am a little frazzled and have made a silly booboo and put things in slightly the wrong order (which would have been corrected anyways).

Comment: Sorry my last comment may have sounded a little harsh. It was just that removing the \s from the pattern in the question changed the meaning somewhat as it was then a different problem being addressed.

Comment: Ah, you're exactly correct. My fault, I'll put it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works just fine to me:

```
function stripJunk($string){
    $string = str_replace(" ", "-", trim($string));
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/", "", $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: I'm flabbergastered. I have absolutely no idea what is different versus my original code - the only difference is that you're adding the "-" to the matching string. This worked, but I cannot say why it's working versus the other solutions I tried. Cheers!

Comment: What you were doing: remove **all** non-letters and convert string to lower case. Code before change didn't work because `!` wasn't followed by the space.

Answer (score 3):

The \s at the end of your pattern means that you will only replace non-alphabetical characters which are immediately followed by a whitespace character. You probably want the \s within the square brackets so that whitespace is also preserved and can later be replaced with a dash.

You will need to add 0-9 inside the square brackets if you want to also allow numbers.

For example:

```
<?php

$string = "Hello World!";

function stripJunk($string){
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $string);
    $string = str_replace(" ", "-", $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);
    return $string;
}

echo stripJunk($string);
```

Comment: Removing the \s still leaves the exclamation point in the string.

Comment: are you sure? I can't reproduce that

Comment: Yup. Very sure. The exclamation point is still appearing in the string.

Comment: Your edit ended up removing the exclamation points, but the spaces were removed - the preg_replace and str_replace just need to be swapped. As with SlientGhost's answer, I have absolutely no idea why it wasn't working.

Comment: $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", "", $string);

Answer (score 1):

You could use some regular expressions in a row to remove the junk:

```
<?php

function strip_junk ($string) {

  // first, strip whitespace; and replace every non-alphabetic character by a dash
  $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9-]/u", "-", strtolower(trim($string)));

  // second, remove double dashes
  $string = preg_replace("/-+/u", "-", $string);

  // finally, remove leading and trailing dashes
  $string = preg_replace("/^-*|-*$/u", "", $string);

  return $string;

}

?>
```

This should do the trick, happy PHP'ing!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
preg_replace("/[.\n\r][^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);
```

if that does not work:

```
preg_replace("/[.\n\r^a-zA-Z]/", "", $string);
```

Does that work?

Comment: Neither worked, sorry. The second one went so far as to remove everything BUT the exclamation points!